# Pythons multiprocess module (with dill) gives an unhelpful AssertionError

Tags: python, parallel-processing, pickle, dill, pathos

I have installed dill/pathos and its dependencies (with some difficulty) and I'm trying to perform a function over several processes. The class/attribute `Model(self.xml,self.exp_data,i).SSR` is custom made and depends on loads of other custom functions so I apologize in advance for not being able to provide 'runnable' code. In brief however, it takes some experimental data, integrates a system of ODE's with python's pysces module and calculates the sum of squares (`SSR`). The purpose for parallelizing this code is to speed up this calculation with multiple parameter sets.

The code:

```
    import multiprocess  
    def evaluate_chisq(pop):

        p = multiprocess.Pool(8)
        res= p.map(lambda i:Model(self.xml,self.exp_data,i).SSR   ,  pop)#calcualteSSR with this parameter set
        return res
```

The error message I get is:

```
  File "C:\Anaconda1\lib\site-packages\multiprocess\pool.py", line 251, in map
    return self.map_async(func, iterable, chunksize).get()

  File "C:\Anaconda1\lib\site-packages\multiprocess\pool.py", line 567, in get
    raise self._value

AssertionError
```

Then I have tried using `map_async` :

```
        def evaluate_chisq(pop):
            p = multiprocess.Pool(8)
            res= p.map_async(lambda i:Model(self.xml,self.exp_data,i).SSR   ,  pop)#calcualteSSR with this parameter set
            return res
```

which returns a `<multiprocess.pool.MapResult object at 0x0000000014AF8C18>` object which gives me the same error when I attempts to use the `MapResult`'s `get' method

```
  File "C:\Anaconda1\lib\site-packages\multiprocess\pool.py", line 567, in get
    raise self._value

AssertionError
```

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I'm the `dill` and `multiprocess` and `pathos` author. It looks like you are  on windows. Are you using `multiprocess.freeze_support`?  This is required in certain situations on Windows.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.freeze_support

Comment: Hi Mike, Yes, I'm using Windows 7 and no I haven't tried `freeze_support`. In fact, this is my first bout of parallel programming so I'm still looking for the best way to do things. But thanks for the response. I'll take a look at freeze_support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Windows you need to use `freeze_support` from `__main__`.

See https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.freeze_support.